# Python embedding in c++ for Socket programming threading issue

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, embedding

I have written a Python script embedded in C++ for socket programming. I have two end systems both of which can send and receive. The send and receive operation happens in different C++ threads. The program build fine but there is a strange error that I encounter when I run .exe file.

Initially I suspected that this is due to the send and receive sockets being the same.
I tied with different sockets too but in vain.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here due to?

The code looks like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI sendPack(LPVOID iValue)
{
    while(1){
       const char* sendPy = "UDPSockSend.sendto('10707',('10.107.35.167',21567))";
       PyRun_SimpleString(sendPy);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI receive(LPVOID iValue){
    while(1){
        Py_Initialize();
        recPy = "data,addr = UDPSockRcv.recvfrom(99000)";
        PyRun_SimpleString(recPy);
    }
    return 0;
}

int threads()
{
    HANDLE sendPackThread, receiveThread;
    DWORD dwGenericThread;

    char lszThreadParam[4];

    receiveThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,receive,&lszThreadParam,0,&dwGenericThread);
    if(receiveThread == NULL){
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    sendPackThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,sendPack,&lszThreadParam,0,&dwGenericThread);
    if(sendPackThread == NULL){
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        std::cout<<"SCM:Error in Creating send sample thread"<<dwError<<"\n" ;
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    Py_Initialize();

    const char * initPy = "import socket;
    UDPSockSend = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
    UDPSockRcv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
    listen_addr = ('',2000);UDPSockRcv.bind(listen_addr)";
    PyRun_SimpleString(initPy);


    int thd = threads();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please append the error.

Comment: Does the communication work when run from python itself (not embedded)?  Anyway, I don't think there is enough information for us to know what is going wrong (incomplete code (socket, bind), no errors)

Comment: The communication works well from python (without embedding). I'm posting the entire code. Please look at it in the original post(not the replies).

Comment: What is the error, and what line of code does it happen on?  (Run in a debugger and give us the line number.)

Comment: The error is because of the two PyRun_SimpleString() commands. Whenever one of these is commented out, the code works all fine!